# Proper way to define url in htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess file:

```
Rewriterule ^view_profile-(.*)$  view.php?user=$1
```

When I do something like `"<a href="view_profile-John">View profile</a>` it works great (URL looks like: `http://home.com/view_profile-John)`. However, if I try this:

`Rewriterule ^view/profile-(.*)$  view.php?id=$1` it says that page cannot be found.

Does anyone know why is not working?

Comment: Because in this case link should be `href="view/profile-John"`

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to turn off Multiviews here. Because the beginning of the request looks like `/view/...` and there's a file `/view.php`, mod_negotiation will automatically assume you mean the php file and route it there before mod_rewrite even gets a chance to do anything. Try adding:

```
Options -Multiviews
```